# Describe function arg. and return in vscode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Is there a build-in way to describe function arguments and what it do for IDE, so when you hover on it in vscode, you will get tooltip?

Something like:

```
function foo(x //integer){
  return x*2 //return square
}
```

Comment: Use [JSDoc](https://jsdoc.app/), [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/), or [Flow](https://flow.org/).

Comment: I think for a non-typed language like Javascript, the IDE will only be able to infer the types based on [JSDocs](https://devhints.io/jsdoc). Even if in your example makes no sense to send a string, it is fully possible to do it in Javascript. You can also start using Typescript in your Javascript projects, where types can be defined in functions declaration and the IDE use this information in the intellisense to help you while developing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VSCode supports [JSDoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSDoc):

```
/**
 * 
 * @param {number} x A value to be doubled
 * @return {number} Twice x.
 *  
 */
function foo(x){
    return x*2 
}

const y = foo(2);
```

(Tested with the language set to Babel JavaScript)

[image: Demo of the above code generating a tooltip]